# Django channels close vs disconnect

Tags: django, django-channels

Sorry for dumb question but I didn't get the idea of this two methods. I can't understand when I should call `close` and when `disconnect`. And also I can't understand why disconnect does not have implementation under the lib's hood?

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html?highlight=disconnect#disconnect) it looks there is no close method

**disconnect**

Closes the socket from the client side. Takes nothing and returns nothing.

You do not need to call this if the application instance you’re testing already exited (for example, if it errored), but if you do call it, it will just silently return control to you

**Note:** Tests are good way to understand how a lib works (beside reading the docs)